# devise sign in page always show up even though its not root.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

It says log in to continue. 
I ve completely removed all excess from layout.html.erb
Only render tag is part of the body. Yet it keeps routing to the users/sign_in page

Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you removed it from your controllers/models too? You can for example have something like this in your model: `before_action :authenticate_member!`

This will cause a redirect to the login page if you're not proper logged in.

Comment: Ty, I figured it out after a lot of head scratching! It was just as you said.

Comment: Hi nice to help you. :-)